# Text Shorten php Tengo un pequeño error

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public function textShorten($text, $limit) {
$text = $text." ";
$text = substr($text, 0, $limit);
$text = substr($text, 0, strrpos($text, ' '));
$text = $text."...";
return $text;
```

}

```
$fm->textShorten($string, 10);
```

esto siemp... deberia mostrarlo asi, pero en el bucle lo si hay una palabla "Hola" muestra hola... no cumple la condicion

Comment: entonces quieres que si text es "Anticonstitucionalmente" y tu limit es 10 quede, "Anticonsti..." pero si text es "Hola" y tu limit es 10 quede "Hola"?

Answer (score 0):

si quieres que tu codigo se ejecute solo cuando `$texto` sea mas grande que `$limit` solo tienes que agregar el `if`:

```
function textShorten($text, $limit) {
    if(strlen($text)>$limit){
        $text = $text." ";
        $text = substr($text, 0, $limit);
        $text = substr($text, 0, strrpos($text, ' '));
        $text = $text."...";
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

según yo tendría que ser algo así:

```
function textShorten($text, $limit) {
    if(strlen($text) > $limit){
        return substr($text, 0, $limit) . '...';
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Espero que se de ayuda.